# how do I get my computer to boot a specific partition?

Tags: dual-boot

My computer has an interesting setup... I have a partition layout that goes like this: 30gb ext4 that I want to boot from, 130gb part ext4 with corrupted drivers (mouse and network are completely offline) that I had originally made as a copy of the 30gb and originally wanted to boot to but now is almost beyond repair but I want to use the home folder on this with the 30gb as the root partition, a 140gb ntfs that I want to install windows 7 on for gaming, and a 1gb partition at the start of the drive that I'd like to use as a grub/boot partition. The other interesting but annoying thing is that the two ext4 partitions seem to irregularly alternate upon reboot, and even a grub boot disk sometimes confuses them. I want to make the 130gb partition not boot, but use it as a home partition for the 30gb one, and have the boot loader installed to the 1gb one at the start of the disk for future expantion and flexibility.

Comment: You could just do a fresh install with manual partitioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform as many installs as you like.  Perform the installs (either Windows or Linux) on which ever partition you want.  As mentioned in the comment above, after any partition, you'll be presented with a boot menu where you can choose which installation you want to boot from.

You can tell the partition by selecting the OS with the up/down arrow and hit "e" for edit which will present some information about that installation to you.

You can also run "sudo upgdate-grub" at anytime to have grub search your system to find the various OS installations and add them to the selectable boot menu.

You can also edit /etc/default/grub and specify "grub_default=#" for your perform default installation to for booting.

After making changes to the /etc/default/grub, you'll have to run "sudo update-grub" to install the changes.